Does interference pattern appears for quantum tunneling particles?
Imagine a quantum particle is shot at a barrier, supposedly this time the luck is on my side and the particle had successfully appears on the other side of the barrier. The barrier is intact and did I forget to mention there is a double slit setup behind the barrier... so if I repeat this many times would there be any interference pattern?

Does a potential $V_1$ (the barrier) in one place affect the solution to the SE at another place with another potential $V_2$ (the slits) in another place?

A potential barrier simply removes part of the energy of the quantum. If your ingoing wave function is sufficiently coherent, then so will the outgoing wave function be and you can use it to illuminate a double slit and get the usual patterns. The whole thing is as boring as it comes, though. One can't learn anything new from it.

There will be an interference pattern but it may be different from the one you would see without the potential since the potential may change relative phases.
